# Update an object with map ( inline es6 )

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this code , it's work

```
series.map( el => {
                if ( !el.label ) {
                    el.label = getTranslation(messages, 'label.unstranslated')
                }
            })
```

But if i do that it's not work

```
         series.map( el => {
                       const obj {...el,label: el.label ? el.label :  getTranslation(messages, 'label.unstranslated')}
                      return obj
        })
```

Obj is updated but series not

Finally I want like this form

```
series.map( el => ({...el,label: el.label ? el.label :  getTranslation(messages,'label.unstranslated')})
```

but it didn't work

Comment: I think the first way is more readable and better

Comment: @MaheerAli I think not at all. It's an abuse of `.map()` which is supposed to change elements of the array, not just iterating and returning nothing. The first way should be replaced with `.forEeach()` if it's more readable.

Comment: If you want to mutate the array, just use `forEach`. `map` should be used when you want to get a new array and don't want to mutate the array. There is no point in doing `series = series.map(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map()` returns new array so you need to assign it to the `series`:

```
var mappedSeries = series.map( el => ({...el,label: el.label || getTranslation(messages,'label.unstranslated')})
```

Comment: `el.label ? el.label :  getTranslation(messages,'label.unstranslated')` could also be `el.label || getTranslation(messages,'label.unstranslated')`

Answer (score 3):

What `map` does it to iterate an array, do something, and return a new array with the items that you returned in the callback.

On your first example, you are altering the objects as you iterate them, and because this is a reference, your items do get altered. On the lines below `el` is a reference to the object been iterated. For something like that, you should consider using `forEach` instead of map.

```
 if ( !el.label ) {
     el.label = getTranslation(messages, 'label.unstranslated')
  }
```

On your 2nd example, you are returning a new object, as you should to work properly with the `map` function, but you are not assigning it to anything, and the items dont get altered because now you are not tampering with the `el`, you just read its values in to a new object, like you should.
So just assign the result to a new variable to test it.

```
   var mapedSeries=  series.map( el => {
           const obj {...el,label: el.label ? el.label :  getTranslation(messages, 'label.unstranslated')}
           return obj;
        })
```

Comment: Upvote for suggesting using `.forEach()` instead of abusing `.map()` ;)